# pull the column value for Min_date & Max date (within 24 months min_date)

Tags: sql, database, hive

Product:

```
+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Product_code | Prod Name |   Status   |    Date    |
+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| A            | AA1       | New        | 12/3/2019  |
| A            | AA2       | Expiry     | 7/20/2017  |
| A            | AA1       | Others     | 8/15/2018  |
| A            | AA1       | Others_Loy | 7/10/2019  |
| B            | BB2       | Expiry     | 8/20/2017  |
| B            | BB1       | Others     | 8/15/2019  |
| B            | BB3       | New        | 7/15/2020  |
| C            | CC1       | Others     | 4/27/2020  |
| D            | DD1       | New        | 12/31/2017 |
| D            | DD3       | Expiry     | 2/15/2020  |
+--------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

expected result: Max_date(within 24 months from min_date)

```
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| Product_code |  Min_date  | Min_status |  Max_date  | Max_status | count_Prod | Label |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| A            | 7/20/2017  | Expiry     | 7/10/2019  | Others_Loy |          3 |     1 |
| B            | 8/20/2017  | Expiry     | 8/15/2019  | Others     |          2 |     1 |
| C            | 4/27/2020  | Others     | 4/27/2020  | Others     |          1 |     0 |
| D            | 12/31/2017 | New        | 12/31/2017 | New        |          1 |     0 |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

I want pull the records from Min_date based on prod_code,
then Max_date need to compute from Min_date to next 24 months (within 24 months time period) and count_prod within that
, Label need to update if count_prod more than one within the 24 months time period.

Trying this sql datbase:

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: Hadoop & querying tool teradata sql assistant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't tagged the database, so this is basically pseudo-code.  In particular, date functionality varies significantly among databases:

```
select product_code, 
       min_date, max(case when date = min_date then status end) as min_status,
       max_date, max(case when date = max_date then status end) as max_status,
       sum(case when date >= max_date - interval '2 year' then 1 else 0 end) as count_prod,
       (case when sum(case when date >= max_date - interval '2 year' then 1 else 0 end) > 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as label
from (select t.*,
             min(date) over (partition by product_code) as min_date,
             max(date) over (partition by product_code) as max_date
      from t
     ) t
group by product_code;
```

You need to adjust this for the database you are using.

Comment: - interval '2 year'  this step couldn't able to run. getting following error.Line 6:51 Wrong arguments ''2 year'': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFOPDTIMinus with (date, string)

Comment: @Vinoth96 . . . You did not have a tag on your question when I answered.  The syntax in Hive is `add_months(max_date, -24)`.